# Remove category link

Tags: categories

I want to use categories but I also want to remove the category pages.

```
http://www.example.com/categories/foo/
```

Assumed that this category exists this URL should return a 301 and redirect to

```
http://example.com/index.php
```

I've tried to add a `category.php` to my theme but this won't work for me.

I don't want to hide posts with a specific category or remove the category base or something like that. I'm using WordPress 3.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hook [`'template_redirect'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect) action hook and redirect if in category using [`wp_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'no_cat_archives');

function no_cat_archives() {
  if ( is_category() ) { wp_redirect( home_url(), 301 ); exit(); }
}
```